# Replace text in textarea script + RTE

Tags: javascript, replace, textarea, rte

I have a javascript code that replace some words writen in text area. Eg. If I write word "dog" it will change it to word "cat".

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeText(){
dt=document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
dt.value=dt.value.replace(/dog/g,"cat");
dt.value=dt.value.replace(/blue/g,"red");
dt.value=dt.value.replace(/good/g,"bad");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="10" cols="65"></textarea> <br>
<input type="button" value="change" onclick="changeText()">
</body>
</html>
```

I have two problems with this script and I don't know how to fix it.

1. How can I call external file with words for replacement? I will have 200+ words and it will better that I have them in separate file.
2. How to implement some simple RTE (eg. Nicedit) and still have working script? I try it and script doesn't work...

Thanks in advance for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Due to security reasons, your possibilites are limited. The best way to do it is to load txt/json/xml file from your server using AJAX technology. Keep in mind that it's an asynchronous method. Without JQuery (most popular JS library), with pure Javascript, you can achieve it with the code below:

   ```
   var fileContent = '';
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest(); // we create a request
   client.open('GET', '/foo.txt'); // foo.txt is the name of the file
   client.onreadystatechange = function() {
     fileContent = client.responseText;
     alert("Hooray! My file was loaded, this is its content: " + fileContent );
   }
   client.send(); // and we send a request
   ```
2. Every rich text editor has its own JS library and a way to get editor's content, so it really depends. For nicedit it's like this (assuming your textarea has an ID):

   ```
   var nicInstance = nicEditors.findEditor('idOfYourTextarea');
   var notes = nicInstance.getContent(); // voila - your content
   ```